# Laravel 3 access all transactions of one customer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

Customers have many Accounts, and Accounts have many Transactions.

I want to get all of the transactions from one customer..?

```
$customer = Auth::user();
$statement = $customers->accounts()->transactions()->where('customer_no', '=',     $customer->customer_no)->get(); //get all transactions
```

I know this doesn't work but this is the closest I can get..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$customer = Auth::user();
$account_ids = $customers->accounts()->lists('id');
$statement = Transaction::where_in('account_id', $account_ids)->where('customer_no', '=', $customer->customer_no)->get(); // Get all transactions
```

You probably do not need the 'customer_no' part b/c

Comment: I did not use the customer part as it was returning a SQL error. Never even knew about lists(). Thanks alot